# "end to end" vs "end-to-end"

Tags: hyphenation

Is there a correct way to spell this idiom?

> end to end
>
> end-to-end

Or is both correct and the latter represents a three-word compound modifier when used as adjective before a noun?

Comment: [End-to-end](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/end-to-end) is an adjective. [End to end](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/end%20to%20end) is an idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "end-to-end"  is an adjective

Whenever you are describing a noun with this term, it is an adjective. Usage example:

> Engineers doing end-to-end development.
>
> Our company offers an end-to-end package from delivery to installation.

### "end to end"  is an idiom

If it is not an adjective, it is an idiom. It describes the sentence instead of modifying a noun.

> Put the tables end to end.
>
> Read a book from end to end.